# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined when using setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im currently building a web interface for a DYI project and im facing an error i cant figure out. Hopefully you can give me a hand. (BTW im a beginner in js/jquery)

This is the piece of code im having problems with.

```
var lights_array = [20, 24, 25, 15, 28, 13, 19, 22, 21, 23, 31, 26, 27, 14, 3, 9, 7, 5, 8, 4, 6, 17, 18, 10, 12, 11, 16, 29, 30]; 

function pull_light_status (lights_array){
    $.each(lights_array,function(myindex, myvalue){
        $.post( "resources/php/individual_json.php", { veraip: "10.20.174.10", device_id: + myvalue})
            .done(function (json) {
            var vera_obj = JSON.parse(json);
            var light_state = vera_obj["Device_Num_"+myvalue].states[1].value;
            if (light_state === "1") {
                $("#light"+myvalue).attr("src","resources/img/on_toggle.png");
            } else {
                $("#light"+myvalue).attr("src","resources/img/off_toggle.png");
            }
            console.log("Checkpoint - Loading light status");
        })  
    })
}

pull_light_status(lights_array);
setInterval(pull_light_status,10000);   //this is what is giving me issues
```

Ok this is the problem i have.  Without the line `setInterval(pull_light_status,10000);` it works fine, when the page loads, it loads the status of my lights and set the images accordingly.

As soon as i add the line `setInterval(pull_light_status,10000);`  so the state lights are refreshed every 10s secons (in case i manually swith the lights on an off) i dont get the checkpoint message every 10 seconds, instead, every 10 seconds i get an error

The error im getting is this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>   n.extend.each @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2
>   pull_light_status @ script2.js:66

PD.  Line 66 of scrip2.js is this
   `$.each(lights_array,function(myindex, myvalue){`

Hopefully you can shed some light of what the problem is and how to resolve it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the function as callback for `setInterval` then you don't send the array as parameter, so the code in the function trying to access the array will fail.

You can put a function wrapper around the code so that you can call the function with the parameter:

```
setInterval(function(){
  pull_light_status(lights_array);
},10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or conversely to Guffa's answer, change the function from:

```
function pull_light_status (lights_array){
```

to this:

```
function pull_light_status (){
```

Because your function has a named parameter, then the function will use this as a local variable. Your setInterval doesn't pass any parameters, so the function sets it as undefined. If you omit the function parameter, it will then look outside the function scope and find your array definition.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance :)